# Vehicle Networking - HTTP to CAN Bus Gateway (Lear) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, data-processing-vehicles, lear, us20130159586

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON IN-FLIGHT/IN-CAR NETWORKING** - This application from [Lear Corporation](http://www.lear.com/) seeks to patent the idea of...a gateway from the Internet to a vehicle! 10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before Dec 15, 2011** that discusses:

> - embedding an **HTTP request** in a **[CAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus) bus-compatible message** and transmitting the CAN bus-compatible message onto a CAN bus

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question.. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - A reference to anything that meets all of the criteria to the question above AND ALSO is compatible with **Ethernet** or communicates with a **Server**

**TITLE: INTERNET TO VEHICLE GATEWAY AND CONTROL SYSTEM**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] A which translates from HTTP to the standard vehicle bus: controller area network ([CAN bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus)) and a controller on the vehicle which responds to the HTTP request.

- **Publication Number**: [US 20130159586 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/US20130159586)
- **Application Number**: 13/712,293
- **Assignee**: Lear Corporation
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** Dec 15, 2011
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO:** Open through Dec 20, 2013
- **Find Prior Art on Google**:  **[Google Link](https://www.google.com/patents/related/US20130159586)**

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A control system for a vehicle, the control system comprising:
>
> 1. a gateway controller configured to embed an HTTP request in a CAN bus-compatible message and transmit the CAN bus-compatible message onto a CAN bus; and
> 2. a remote controller configured to receive the CAN bus-compatible message from the CAN bus, extract the HTTP request from the CAN bus-compatible message, and create an HTTP response to the HTTP request.

In English this means:

> A vehicle control system, comprising:
>
> 1. A gateway from the Internet (HTTP) to a vehicle (CAN bus)
> 2. A controller on the vehicle which receives CAN bus, extracts HTTP request and creates an HTTP response.

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to the Dec 15, 2011.

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming using gateway which ALSO is compatible with **Ethernet** or communicates with a **Server**

---

**"Controllers communicate through a CAN bus in a vehicle and connected through a gateway controller with an Ethernet network” from the Applicant**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Answer (score 1):

1. In 2002 the following paper (A publisher/subscriber architecture supporting interoperability of the CAN bus and the internet) was published:

   http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Paper/2055842

   The paper specifically describes a CAN bus, a gateway, and the internet
2. There is also a 2009 paper (Bringing Best Practices from Web Development Into the Vehicle):

   http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Publication/5787722/bringing-best-practices-from-web-development-into-the-vehicle

   This describes an http wrapper around the CAN bus so http messages can be sent to the vehicle, translated down then issued to (for example) the ecu

Answer (score 1):

NASA actually did this in the early to mid 2000's with a 757 "Aries" flying lab aircraft.  A FIOA request to Langley will turn up some of the design documents.   Ask for aft cockpit as well as ARIES and 757.

http://www.cs.odu.edu/~mln/ltrs-pdfs/NASA-aiaa-2002-5822.pdf

http://foia.larc.nasa.gov/

http://www.nasa.gov/centers/langley/news/factsheets/757.html

Some of the 737 documents from NASA might be relevant too.

http://history.nasa.gov/SP-4216.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I know for certain of prior art: see

"SAE J 1939 Over Real Time Ethernet: The Future of Heavy Duty Vehicle Networks"
doi:10.4271/2012-01-1988
Author: Massimiliano Ruggeri of IMAMOTER C.N.R. – Institute for Agricultural and
Earthmoving Machines, National Research Council of Italy

and references therein, such as

1. Fellmeth, P. “CAN-based tractor agricultural implement
   communication ISO11783”. 2003-09. http://www.cancia.org.
2. Ole, Peters, Peters, Pickel, Nicolai, Tarasinski, Real Time
   Ethernet for Tractor Implement Communication, 68
   Internationale Tagunng Landtechnik, 27, 28 October 2010 -
   Braunsweig, VDI - Verlag Dusseldorf, 2010 ISSN
   0083-5560, pagg. 285-292.
3. Decotignie, J. D. “Ethernet-based real-time and industrial
   communications”, Proc. IEEE, vol. 93, p.1102, 2005.

I will call this page to Prof. Ruggeri's attention.

Answer (score 1):

Dear Lear Corporation I'm Massimiliano Ruggeri, a Researcher of the National Research Council of Italy. We are working on Embedding CAN on a Ethernet communication and vice versa since 2008.
We work both on wireless over WI-FI to synchronize vehicles and to perform fleet management and on Wired Ethernet for in-machine communication. We also designed and published several papers on a CAN/Ethernet Gateway design and testing and we also implemented it.

You can refer:

1) Wireless Communication Protocol for Agricultural Machines Synchronization and Fleet Management, Alfredo Revenaz, Massimiliano Ruggeri, Massimo Martelli, IEEE-ISIE 2010

2) Low Latency WI-FI Real-Time Protocol for Agricultural Machines Synchronization Using Linux RT Kernel, Alfredo Revenaz, Massimiliano Ruggeri, Velio Tralli, IEEE-ISIE 2011

3) Improvements of Determinism in WI-FI Real-Time Protocol for Agricultural Machine Clusters, Massimiliano Ruggeri, Giorgio Malaguti, Massimo Martelli, IEEE-ISIE 2012

4) Dian M.; Malaguti G.; Ruggeri M. A Real-Time Wireless Protocol Proposal for Remote Agricultural Machine Control in 7Th FPNI Phd Symposium

5) Ruggeri M., Malaguti G., Dian M., Quasi Isochronous Wireless Communication Protocol for Co-Operative Heavy-Duty Vehicle Clusters in 12th European Conference of the ISTVS

6) Malaguti G.; Dian M.; Ruggeri M., Real Time Distributed Control on Machines Over Quasi Deterministic Ethernet in 7Th FPNI Phd Symposium On Fluid Power

7) Ruggeri M.; Malaguti G.; Dian. M., Real Time Ethernet for Heavy-Duty Vehicle Powertrain Control in 12th European Conference of the ISTVS

8) Ruggeri M.; Malaguti G.; Dian M., SAE J 1939 Over Real Time Ethernet: The Future Of Heavy Duty Vehicle Networks in SAE 2012 Commercial Vehicle Engineering Congress, Rosemont, Illinois, USA, October 2-3, 2012

9)  Ferraresi C.; Dian M.; Malaguti G.; Ruggeri M., Isobus Over Ethernet: A First Implementation in 7Th FPNI Phd Symposium On Fluid Power.

The CAN message Vs TCP/UDP/IP message under HTTP is well explained in the paper 1), and in the other papers the analysis is performed on specific CAN networks for heavy-duty and for Agricultural vehicles, where international standards set a lot of requirements.

- In the ISO TC 023/SC 19/WG 5 a new standard for wireless communication on this target is under development. Please refer to the Convener Prof. Daan Goense (daan.goense@wur.nl)
- In the ISO TC 023/SC 19/WG 1 a task force is working on the same argument for wired communication. Please refer to the Convener Jaap van Bergeijk (jacob.vanbergeijk@agcocorp.com)

Please feel free to contact me for any questions: m.ruggeri@imamoter.cnr.it, massimiliano.ruggeri@cnr.it, massimiliano.ruggeri@unife.it.

Comment: Massimiliano, Thanks for participating. AskPatents is an online service in Q&A format where users like you help find **prior art** on **US Patent Applications**. This prior art request was posted by the community in response to an overly broad patent application from Lear. The prior art discovered here will be submitted to the USPTO by Ask Patents through the 2012 [America Invents Act - Pregrant Process](http://bit.ly/NRggd7).   Please see [faq] for more information about AskPatents and we welcome your ongoing participation.

Comment: Our site's style is to not have signatures or contact info in posts but have them in our profile.

Comment: ok sorry, i didn't have a profile..... now I received the feedback request for mail confirmation and I will create a profile.